# Is there a way to match recursively/nested with regex? (PHP, preg_match_all)

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

How can I match both `(http://[^"]+)`'s?:

```
<a href="http://yoursite.com/goto/http://aredirectURL.com/extraqueries"></a>
```

(I know it's an illegal URL, but same idea)

I want the regex to give me these two matches:

```
1 http://yoursite.com/goto/http://aredirectURL.com/extraqueries
2 http://aredirectURL.com/extraqueries
```

Without running multiple preg_match_all's

Really stumped, thanks for any light you can shed.

Comment: Arbitrarily nested, or up to two? (The former is impossible with a single PHP regular expression.)

Comment: @minitech [recursive regexes man!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3180176/31671) :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regular expression will get you the output you want: `((?:http://[^"]+)(http://[^"]+))`. Note the usage of the non-capturing group `(?:regex)`. To read more about non-capturing groups, see [Regular Expression Advanced Syntax Reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html).

```
<?php
preg_match_all(
    '((?:http://[^"]+)(http://[^"]+))',
    '<a href="http://yoursite.com/goto/http://aredirectURL.com/extraqueries"></a>',
    $out);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($out);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

The above code outputs the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://yoursite.com/goto/http://aredirectURL.com/extraqueries
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://aredirectURL.com/extraqueries
        )

)
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks!

Here is what I ended up doing:  `/((?:http[^\"\'\s>]+)?(http[^\"\'\s>]+))/gism`

Answer (score 0):

you can split the string with this function:

http://de.php.net/preg_split

each part can contain e.g. one of the urls in the array given in the result.

if there is more content maybe call the preg_split using a callback operation while your full text is "worked" on.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = '<a href="http://yoursite.com/goto/http://aredirectURL.com/extraqueries"></a>';

preg_match("/\"(http:\/\/.*?)(http:\/\/.*?)\"/i", $str, $match);

echo "{$match[0]}{$match[1]}\n";
echo "{$match[1]}\n";
```